# How to assume a nested map as a prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, data-structures, struct, prototype

```js
const Box = {
  pick: function(...fruits) {
    this.fruits = "You've picked the fruits " + fruits;
  $('span[data-count]').text(this.fruits);
  }
}
var Box2 = Object.create(Box);
Box2.prototype.newMethod = function() {
  $('span[data-count]').text(this.fruits);
}
Box2.pick('Apple'); // Prototype?
Box.pick('Orange', 'Mango', 'Blueberry'); // Original
```

```css
* {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}
```

```html
<span data-count></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/o22/pen/bZVWOJ

I'm stuck to get the function `pick` that inside of `const Box` by using `prototype` property.

Assuming `pick` through `Box2` directly is working fine. But the browser fires an error when I put `Box2.prototype.newMethod` in the code.

My goal is to use `prototype` property for making new methods and accessing the `pick` function.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototype` **property** is specific to constructor functions, it *isn't* the prototype of the object itself. (If you wanted to get the prototype of the object, you'd use `Object.getPrototypeOf` [you might also see code using the deprecated `__proto__` accessor property; don't use it in new code].)

Your `Box2` isn't a constructor function, it's just an object. So if you want to add a new method, you just do that directly:

```
const Box = {
  pick: function(...fruits) {
    this.fruits = "You've picked the fruits " + fruits;
  $('span[data-count]').text(this.fruits);
  }
}
var Box2 = Object.create(Box);
Box2.newMethod = function() {
//  ^---- no .prototype here *********************************
  $('span[data-count]').text(this.fruits);
}
Box2.pick('Apple'); // Prototype?
Box.pick('Orange', 'Mango', 'Blueberry'); // Original
```

`Box2` will have its own `newMethod`, and will inherit `pick` from its prototype (`Box`).

Simpler example:

```js
const a = {
  method1() {
    console.log("this is method1");
  }
};
const b = Object.create(a);
b.method2 = function() {
  console.log("this is method2");
};

b.method1();
b.method2();
```

As a minor refinement, when defining an object with a specific prototype and some methods you want to add, `Object.assign` is fairly handy:

```js
const a = {
  method1() {
    console.log("this is method1");
  }
};
const b = Object.assign(Object.create(a), {
  method2() {
    console.log("this is method2");
  }
});

b.method1();
b.method2();
```

---

Since these aren't constructor functions, the *overwhelmingly common* convention in JavaScript would be to not capitalize them. So `box` and `box2`, not `Box` and `Box2`.